# Using a function on data output in a table with Angular repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object

I'm fairly new to writing decent JS and totally new to Angular.

I'm trying out building a very small app that takes data from an external JSON, and outputs it into a table. I've done that part and now I want to play around with manipulating some of the data.

I output my data into a table using Angular `ng-repeater`:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="pattern in pattern">
   <td>{{ pattern.brand }}</td>
   <td>{{ pattern.name }}</td>
   <td>{{ pattern.size }}</td>
   <td>{{ pattern.quantity}}</td>
   <td>{{ pattern.fabricType }}</td>
 </tr>
```

This all works just fine ([see this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKLqWw?editors=1010)).

Now I want to start manipulating the data by creating some custom functions. I read a tutorial that had a short function that concatenated data from `firstName` and `lastName` fields into `fullName` and output them in the table. The function looked like this:

```
fullName: function() {
  var studentObject;
  studentObject = $scope.student;
  return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
}
```

reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_tables.htm

And it was called using `{{student.fullName()}}` in the HTML. I want to do something similar. If my `quantity` data = `-1` I actually want to output it as `Unlimited` in the table.

I wrote this function:

```
// Function to name the quantity field correctly
    function quantityLabel() {
        if ($scope.pattern.quantity == -1){
            return 'Unlimited';
        }else {
            return quantity;
        }
    }
```

But I can't work out a succinct way to write a function like this and call it in the template, like in the tutorial.

[Here's my broken codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBWQzL?editors=1010). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your controller:

```
$scope.quantityLabel = function (quantity) {
    return quantity === -1 ? 'Unlimited' : quantity;
}
```

And then in your template call it like this:

```
<td>{{quantityLabel(pattern.quantity)}}</td>
```

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify a bit on what is going on here, you want to attach a function to the scope that takes the quantity value, modifies it and returns the value you want.  As you can see the scope function takes a parameter "quantity" and returns a string "infinity" if the value is -1.  If not, it returns the original quantity.  In the template, we are calling this function passing `$scope.pattern.quantity`.

Each digest cycle, angular will pass `$scope.pattern.quantity` into the function and display it's return value.

Comment: Thanks! This works to run the function :) Can you give me a little more information about exactly what's going on and what the syntax means and why it's used? I'm trying to learn :)

Comment: I've updated the answer with a clarification of what is happening in the code.  Let me know if you need more information or have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what @instantaphex answered is correct and good. You can also write it directly in the view:

```
<td>{{ pattern.quantity === -1 ? 'Unlimited' : pattern.quantity }}</td>
```

You can also add a small directive for that (directives are used for reuable components):

```
myApp.directive('quantity', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '{{fooValue === -1 ? "Unlimited" : fooValue}}',
        scope: {
            fooValue: '=value'
        }
    }
});
```

And use it in your HTML:

```
<td><quantity value="pattern.quantity"></quantity></td>
```

In this way you don't have to copy-paste your same logic if used in different pages.

See a working example below:

```js
var tableApp = angular.module("tableApp", []);

tableApp.controller('patternController', function($scope) {
  $scope.pattern = data;
});

tableApp.directive('quantity', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '{{finalQuantity}}',
    scope: {
      fooValue: '=value'
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      if ($scope.fooValue === -1) {
        $scope.finalQuantity = 'Unlimited';
      } else {
        $scope.finalQuantity = $scope.fooValue;
      }
    }
  }
});

var data = [{
  "id": "0001",
  "brand": "New Look",
  "name": "NL6209",
  "size": "O/S",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0002",
  "brand": "Vogue",
  "name": "8983",
  "size": "16-24",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }, {
    "id": "1006",
    "type": "Tunic"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0003",
  "brand": "McCalls",
  "name": "6696",
  "size": "16-24",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }, {
    "id": "2002",
    "type": "Cut"
  }],
  "quantity": 3,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0004",
  "brand": "Simplicity",
  "name": "1669",
  "size": "16-24",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }, {
    "id": "1002",
    "type": "Top"
  }, {
    "id": "1003",
    "type": "Jacket"
  }, {
    "id": "1004",
    "type": "Trouser"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2002",
    "type": "Cut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0005",
  "brand": "Vogue",
  "name": "8577",
  "size": "16-22",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2002",
    "type": "Cut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0006",
  "brand": "Butterick",
  "name": "5898",
  "size": "XL-6X",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }, {
    "id": "1003",
    "type": "Jacket"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0007",
  "brand": "McCalls",
  "name": "6741",
  "size": "18W-24W",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0008",
  "brand": "Simplicity",
  "name": "1101",
  "size": "20W-28W",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0009",
  "brand": "Butterick",
  "name": "6185",
  "size": "14-22",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }, {
    "id": "1002",
    "type": "Top"
  }, {
    "id": "1003",
    "type": "Jacket"
  }, {
    "id": "1004",
    "type": "Trouser"
  }, {
    "id": "1005",
    "type": "Skirt"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0010",
  "brand": "McCalls",
  "name": "6713",
  "size": "18W-24W",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "knit"
}, {
  "id": "0011",
  "brand": "Kwik Sew",
  "name": "4068",
  "size": "O/S",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0012",
  "brand": "McCalls",
  "name": "7381",
  "size": "L-XXL",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0013",
  "brand": "Kwik Sew",
  "name": "3874",
  "size": "O/S",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }, {
    "id": "1006",
    "type": "Tunic"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0014",
  "brand": "Vogue",
  "name": "9146",
  "size": "14-22",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0015",
  "brand": "McCalls",
  "name": "7350",
  "size": "14-22",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0016",
  "brand": "Vogue",
  "name": "1484",
  "size": "14-22",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0017",
  "brand": "Lekala",
  "name": "4456",
  "size": "Custom",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1002",
    "type": "Top"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2003",
    "type": "Printed"
  }],
  "quantity": -1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0018",
  "brand": "Lekala",
  "name": "5569",
  "size": "Custom",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1003",
    "type": "Jacket"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2003",
    "type": "Printed"
  }],
  "quantity": -1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0019",
  "brand": "Lekala",
  "name": "5092",
  "size": "Custom",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1005",
    "type": "Skirt"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2003",
    "type": "Printed"
  }],
  "quantity": -1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0020",
  "brand": "Lekala",
  "name": "5454",
  "size": "Custom",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1003",
    "type": "Jacket"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2003",
    "type": "Printed"
  }],
  "quantity": -1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0021",
  "brand": "Lekala",
  "name": "5229",
  "size": "Custom",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1007",
    "type": "Intimates"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2003",
    "type": "Printed"
  }],
  "quantity": -1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0022",
  "brand": "Lekala",
  "name": "2022",
  "size": "Custom",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2003",
    "type": "Printed"
  }],
  "quantity": -1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0023",
  "brand": "Lekala",
  "name": "4508",
  "size": "Custom",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2003",
    "type": "Printed"
  }],
  "quantity": -1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0024",
  "brand": "Lekala",
  "name": "4278",
  "size": "Custom",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2003",
    "type": "Printed"
  }],
  "quantity": -1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0025",
  "brand": "Lekala",
  "name": "4474",
  "size": "Custom",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1008",
    "type": "Coat"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2003",
    "type": "Printed"
  }],
  "quantity": -1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0026",
  "brand": "Lekala",
  "name": "5234",
  "size": "Custom",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1007",
    "type": "Intimates"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2003",
    "type": "Printed"
  }],
  "quantity": -1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0027",
  "brand": "Lekala",
  "name": "4533",
  "size": "Custom",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1002",
    "type": "Top"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2003",
    "type": "Printed"
  }],
  "quantity": -1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0028",
  "brand": "Lekala",
  "name": "5958",
  "size": "Custom",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1002",
    "type": "Top"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2003",
    "type": "Printed"
  }],
  "quantity": -1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0029",
  "brand": "Style Arc",
  "name": "5958",
  "size": "22",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }, {
    "id": "1006",
    "type": "Tunic"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}, {
  "id": "0030",
  "brand": "Thread Count",
  "name": "1501",
  "size": "16-24",
  "type": [{
    "id": "1001",
    "type": "Dress"
  }],
  "condition": [{
    "id": "2001",
    "type": "Uncut"
  }],
  "quantity": 1,
  "fabricType": "woven"
}]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<main>
  <h1>Test Table</h1>
  <div ng-app="tableApp" ng-controller="patternController">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <th>Name/ID</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Fabric type</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="pattern in pattern">
        <td>{{ pattern.brand }}</td>
        <td>{{ pattern.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ pattern.size }}</td>
        <td>
          <quantity value="pattern.quantity"></quantity>
        </td>
        <td>{{ pattern.fabricType }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: This will work just fine, although I think a better practice is to keep view logic in the controller as much as possible.

Comment: Yes, it depends. If the same thing needs to be displayed on multiple pages then you have to copy paste the same scope function to every controller. Then the directive will be helpful. Well, it depends on the author, how they want to use.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal is there a way to place scope functions elsewhere that can be used by multiple controllers? Can I define them in a global file and then import them in per-controller as and when needed?

Comment: Well, the global place to register is the `$rootScope` but it is not recommended to work with `$rootScope`. So you should be using the directive example I mentioned. The directives are meant to be used for reusable component (that is your scenario in this case). Other than this, you can create a global controller and add that in your body or html tag like `<body ng-controller="GlobalCtrl">` and move your method here so that it will be now available in every page (an alternative to `$rootScope`.